# How to amend existing axes on a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, axis, axes

I'm editing a plot. I am making mistakes with axes formatting and want to fix them. However, if I write a right code after the wrong one, the new axes are added on top of existing axes, not replacing them. Is there a better way to amend axes without starting drawing the plot from the scratch?

This is the code:

```
library("sp")

#Prepare data
data("meuse.riv")
meuse.lst <- list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)),"meuse.riv"))
meuse.sr <- SpatialPolygons(meuse.lst)

#Create the plot
plot(meuse.sr, axes = F)
axis(1, at = c(178000 + 0:2 * 2000), cex.axis = 0.7)
#Code with a mistake: I need 3 stretches insted of 2

axis(1, at = c(178000 + 0:3 * 2000), cex.axis = 0.7)
#Right code but new axis is added to the old one; it can be seen because old part looks bolder

axis(2, at = c(326000 + 0:3 * 4000))
#Code with a mistake: I need smaller font (cex.axis = 0.7)

axis(2, at = c(326000 + 0:3 * 4000), cex.axis = 0.7)
#Right code but new labels are laid over the old ones. They are not readable.
```

The result is this:
[image]

Comment: Use `ggplot` and save the plot into an object. Then you can add stuff or change the layout afterwards without having to compute the plot again.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways of saving R base graphics and re-plotting it:

```
library("sp")

pdf(NULL)
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
#Prepare data
data("meuse.riv")
meuse.lst <- list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)),"meuse.riv"))
meuse.sr <- SpatialPolygons(meuse.lst)

#Create the plot
plot(meuse.sr, axes = F)
axis(1, at = c(178000 + 0:2 * 2000), cex.axis = 0.7)

my.plot1 <- recordPlot()
invisible(dev.off())

# Display the saved plot
grid::grid.newpage()
my.plot1
```

Much easier approach is to use pryr library:

```
library(pryr)

my.plot2 %<a-% {

  #Prepare data
  data("meuse.riv")
  meuse.lst <- list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)),"meuse.riv"))
  meuse.sr <- SpatialPolygons(meuse.lst)

  #Create the plot
  plot(meuse.sr, axes = F)
  axis(1, at = c(178000 + 0:2 * 2000), cex.axis = 0.7)
}
my.plot2
```